# ASP updateprogress close button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp-classic

I have a problem with my updateprogress. Its working, but I want a close button to close it. Its not problem yet, but I want to display this button after display of updateprogress in 30 sec. I tried do it with jquery, but it didnt work.
Can you help me?

Here is a sample. My problem is, that I dont know, what kind of event show the updateprogress.

```
$('.UpdateProgress').on('display', function () {
    $('.btnClose').hide(0).delay(30000).show(0);
});
```

I tried display, show, focus event, but I dont know how to do this.

Comment: Can you share more details on what you have already tried? Very hard for anyone to guess what kind of code you already have. Presumably a _setTimeout(function(){ /* code to close button/div/whatever */ }, 30000);_ will do

Comment: Sorry, its my first question.
I can show the button, but I cant delay it.

Answer (score 0):

Set your button to hidden to start:

```
<style>
    input.btnClose
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<input type="submit" class="btnClose">
```

Now use setTimeout to show() it after 30000ms (30 seconds):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.UpdateProgress').on('display', function () {
            setTimeout("showDelay();", 30000);
        });
    });

    function showDelay() {
        $('.btnClose').show();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it didnt work for me, the button do nothing for the display event of the UpdateProgress, what can be the problem?

Comment: Perhaps I misread your problem. Are you not getting the .on('display') event to fire at all? I assumed since you didn't show any markup/code for UpdateProgress that this piece was working fine. If you need a selector for the visible state of a panel, div, etc...try     $('.UpdateProgress').css('visibility') == 'visible'  OR  $('.UpdateProgress').is(':visible')

Comment: thank you, I will try it, it seems to be a better options, because I dont know the events of the updateprogress that I could get in js